# Complex Type Ordering in Enterprise Architect Sparx Systems

Tags: xml, parsing, xsd, enterprise-architect, complextype

I am running into an issue in Enterprise Architect 16.1. I need to be able to out output an xsd from a very complex garden of eden style UML model with the complex types maintaining a strict parsing order, not alphabetical order. How do I do that? The tree which populates the model/diagram always reverts to alphabetical order?

I am new to both Enterprise-Architect (16.1) and generating artifacts directly from a UML model. The data governance procedures I work with require this strict xsd parse ordered complex type ordering come directly from the UML model output, not via a script, XSLT, or any other process in-between the xsd output and the UML model. Has anyone been able to successfully enforce specific complex type ordering in Enterprise Architect 16.1 directly from the UML diagram?

Comment: "The tree which populates the model/diagram always reverts to alphabetical order?" What do you mean by that?

Comment: Simply put we wrote our own XSD ex-/import since EA's basics were just too basic and not configurable for our needs. It was not _that_ complicated.

Comment: @qwerty_so our data governance policy won't allow an XSD ex-/import. The xsd has to be extrapolated directly from the model in parsing order.

Comment: @Geert Bellekens the "Browser" tree which shows the complex types only allows them listed in alphabetical order. Our previous UML software allowed the tree which listed the complex types to be set to parsing order rather than alphabetical. Then when you output the xsd from the model, it was output in that unique order which was uniquely configured in the Browser tree. We switched to EA due to pricing and the difficulty supporting the older UML software and now it appears EA won't manage hierarchical complex type order anyway but alphabetically directly from the model. Which won't work for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Geert Bellekens, to be honest, I don't know where the actual setting exists in the UI. I tried to move the element order around (right click on a specific element, then use the  move up or move down options) within the Feature box and a prompt box opened up telling me element ordering was set to alphabetical. It asked me if I wanted to turn that option off. I clicked yes, and it let me move the elements around as needed. That single option change resolved all my "garden of Eden" style complex type ordering issues.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set EA to allow free sorting in the project browser using the preferences:

[image]

After setting that, you can move the classes in the project browser using the up/down buttons on top of the project browser:

[image]

This doesn't however appear to change anything to the order of elements generated in the XSD. It looks like the only way is to use some kind of post processing.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I asked the wrong question. Simply by turning off the alphabetical ordering constraint within EA, the schema is not output in the expected hierarchical order.
[image: EA Schema Complex Type Ordering]

Comment: Can you explain **how** to turn off that *alphabetical ordering constraint*? Your answer currently doesn't specify that.